# What is this manga about two students who speak to each other through a window?

Tags: shuu-7

The manga is about a girl who sits in the bench in classroom near the window and a random student shows up outside at the other side of the window and starts talking to her. Every now and then he shows up and talks to her and she starts to develop feelings for him. One day he stops showing up and she realized he was in the hospital. She goes there to meet him and they hug or something. He was like really ill and he left the hospital every day to see her near the window. They end up together at the end.

I am almost sure it is one-shot manga, definitely shoujo, school-life. I've read it few years ago, It's not really a new manga. The art is really pretty ^^. I know the main girl character has black hair.

I would be so happy if someone can recognize that manga and tell me the name. I'm kind of desperate. Thanks! <3

Comment: Currently your question does not satisfy [the guidelines](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/892/63) for "identification-request" question. Please consider adding some details to your question, such as (but not limited to) one or more of the following: whether this manga was a one-shot, serial, standalone work? When and where did you last read it? What genre was it (shoujo, shounen, seinin, jousei, etc.)?

Comment: I almost sure it is one-shot manga, definitely shoujo, school-life. I've read it few years ago, It's not really a new manga. The art is really pretty ^^ I know the main girl character has black hair.

Comment: Please edit your question to include these details.

Answer (score 5):

I have been searching for this manga too and I hope it's the same manga you were searching for.

The name of the manga is [**Shuu 7**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=12781). The manga consists of 4 one-shot stories and the story you are looking for is the third one.

> 3) Koi no Kajitsu (Fruit of Love)
>
> Yuzuhara had to quit the track and field team due to an injury and is down because of that...then one day Tooda Shuuhei pops in at the window where she sits and asks her to date him...although shocked Yuzuhara agrees him to see at her window seat for a month until her seat changes...but on the last day before her seat changes Shuuhei doesn't turn up...